# How to make an edittext fit between two buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 3 buttons and I want to make a text field between them, 
here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/selecmain"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#514e4e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#514e4e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Write something here."
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/count"
    android:maxLength="140"
    android:background="@null">
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="140/140"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:onClick="setBtnRecord"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like the edittext to fill the space between button2 and button3, but I can't simply make it below the button since I want to have a boarder for the edittext as well. My intention is to let the user know those large area is for them to write something. 
In addition, I sometimes will make button2 invisible, but I want the edittext remain the same position just like the button2 is there.

I know it has something to do with the edittext's height, but I am not sure how to make it fit to different screen size or even just in one size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/selecmain"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#514e4e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#514e4e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Write something here."
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/count"
    android:maxLength="140"
    android:background="@null">
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="140/140"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:onClick="setBtnRecord"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I can't even find where to type in the edittext.

Comment: Again, thank you for your answer, but I am actually looking for something different, here is the screen shot of a hard code version of what I want: https://gyazo.com/085e71e75665db9c03be46a8d06b0164

Comment: it would have been better if you had attached the screen shot earlier. Anyways updated the answer

Comment: Sorry mb, first time asking a question, really thank you for the answer, that's what I'm looking for.